# forward inline keyboard along message in telegram

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I want to create a message with telegram api that users could share(forward) it along its inline keyboard buttons. 
I know with telegram api you can create a message that contains inline keyboard by adding `inline_keyboard` array in `replay_markup` of a `message` but when I forward this message inside telegram just the text part of the message forwards and buttons wont. 
In brief I want to know is it possible to create a message with telegram api that when someone forwards this message inline keyboard of that message forwards too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't attach inline keyboard in the forwarded message, but you can add a “Share” button, and use `switch_inline_query` in [inline keyboard](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardbutton).

For instance: Users can use `@Sean_Bot TeleBot` to send a photo with inline buttons, if they want to keep inline buttons, they should click “Share” button instead of directly forward.

Comment: Hi @sean, how to add "share" button? I know how to add inline keyboard but i don't know what URL to use so that the "share" inline keyboard will work.

Answer (score 4):

InlineKeyboardButton with "url" or "login_url" parameter can be forwarded.
Note: if there is another button in keyboard without "url" or "login_url" parameter whole keyboard woudn't be shown

Comment: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardbutton
There are two optional fields for the InlineKeyboardButton such as `url` and `login_url`.
If all keyboard buttons will be with one of these two fields, the whole keyboard will be preserved when forwarding